Can't access to /public/ folder en HTTPS
can someone help me with this?
So i use ViteJS with react and i have a button to open PDF in new tab.
<a href='/pdf/carnival-texts/mypdf.pdf'>Test LINK</a>
<a href='FULLLINK/pdf/carnival-texts/mypdf.pdf'>Test FULL LINK</a>

When I click i have a 404
When I refresh(F5) on pdf page I have 404
But when I force refresh (CTRL+F5) on pdf page it works
And this only when i'm on HTTPS, on same website with HTTP it work perfectly
I test this on apache and nginx and on OVH free-hosting
I have CA SSL certificat and not self-signed
Thanks
First, I thought it was the server (Apache/nginx) but I think it's not, and I don't have control over / can't modify the configuration. But after that, I absolutely don't know what I can do

Now what are you using, apache or nginx?
